# Image warping matlab

Tags: matlab

Having some issues with image warping a section of an image. Right now, I'm trying to use affine2d and imwarp functions. Right now, I'm trying to just warp the entire image

```
img_data = double(imread('lenna.tif'));
theta =-30;
A_rot = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0 ; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0 ; 0 0 1];
A_rot_tform = affine2d(A_rot);
invt_A_rot = invert(A_rot_tform);


B = imwarp(img_data, A_rot_tform); imshow(B); impixelinfo;
C = imwarp(B, invt_A_rot); imshow(C);
```

Meanwhile, the images displayed for B and C are simply black and white boxes. B is black background with white box rotated and C is black background with white box rotation reversed. I thought this would be applying the rotation to the image? Meanwhile, if I have a specific area of my image I'm wanting to apply this to, I do not see how to do that either. Any recommendations?

**img is RGB

Comment: convert image to double using `im2double` so values will range in [0..1] (and not [0..255]). I believe the warping is fine, you have problems with `imshow` that expects double precision images in range [0..1] thus any pixel with value larger than 1 is white. try `imshow(B,[0 255])` this might scale things for you...

Comment: @user2208604 - Shai is correct.  `imshow(B,[])` is what you'd need for a quick fix.